# Array to string conversion in C://... in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv, array-map

I wanna import data from CSV file and print it on a webpage using PHP.
first I tried it with **print_r()** it worked perfectly. But, when I tried to print each value in the array individually the error "**Array to string conversion**"
how to prevent this error and access each array value individually?
Here is the code

```
<?php $csv =array_map('str_getcsv', file('kishore.csv'));print_r($csv);echo "\n$csv[0]";?>
```

Here is the output
[image: output]

Comment: What is the OP of `print_r($csv);`?

Comment: I dare say there are millions of examples for iterating over an array to output its individual values...

Comment: @SougataBose I placed the output.

Comment: Your `$csv[0]` contains array or values, so it can't be printed.

Comment: Not sure what you're up to but maybe learning about the "fgetcsv" method helps you. See also the example code in http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the array to the string using the Implode function. You can convert the array into string by using NULL value.
Here attaching a snippet of working code:

```
<?php 
$csv =array_map('str_getcsv', file('abc.csv'));
print_r($csv); 
echo implode("",$csv[0]);
?>
```